# Given two arrays and an upper limit, what is the most efficient way to get the index pair for which the sum is maximum and below the upper limit?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two arrays A and B and an upper limit k, what will the most efficient way to compute the index pair (i, j) such that given,

```
s = A[i] + B[j]

s = max(A[a] + B[b]) for a = 0, 1, 2, .. , len(A)-1 and b = 0, 1, 2, .. , len(B)-1
and
s < k
```

For example,

```
Given, 
A = [9,2,5]
B = [2,1,6]
k = 5

we get,
s = 2 + 2 = 4 < 5
and hence,
i = 1 and j = 0
```

So the output should be (1,0)

A straight-forward approach would be looping through all the elements of A and B but that would make the worst case time complexity O(nm) where n = len(A) and m = len(B).

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorting always helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort for A and B. Then you can use an early break once you are >= k. The function below returns indices, s.t. A[i] + B[j] < k and A[p] + B[q] < A[i] + B[j], for all p < i and for all q < j.

```py
    def sum_less_than_k(A, B, k):
            i_max = -1
            j_max = -1
            s_max = -np.inf
            for i, a in enumerate(A):
                if a + B[0] >= k:
                    break
                for j, b in enumerate(B):
                    if a + b >= k:
                        break
                    if a + b > s_max:
                        s_max = a + b
                        i_max = i
                        j_max = j
        
            return i_max, j_max

    A.sort()
    B.sort()
    i, j = sum_less_than_k(A, B, k)
```

I wrote the code for Saurab's suggestion as well which is way faster for large k relative to what's in the list. However, for rather short lists or small k the two for loops are faster according to some sample runs.

```py
def sum_less_than_k(A, B, k):
    i_max = j_max = -1
    s_max = -np.inf
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        j = bisect(B, k - a - 1)
        if len(B) > j > -1 and k > A[i] + B[j] > s_max:
            s_max = A[i] + B[j]
            i_max = i
            j_max = j

    return i_max, j_max

B.sort()
i, j = sum_less_than_k(A, B, k)
```

Comment: In worst case I think it is still O(n*m) because in some test cases  both loop will execute without break statement.

Comment: True, if the limit k is too high you have to iterate until the last elements of A and B to get the maximal sum.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problems can be solved by sorting one of the array.

**One Approach could be this ::**

1. make an array `temp` of tuples such that each tuple will be `(value,index)` where `value` is item of `B` and `index` is its corresponding `index in B`.
2. Now, sort this temp array with respect to `first item of tuple i.e, value`.
3. iterate through array `A` and using `Binary Search` find the `Lower bound` of `K - A[i]` in temp array. let it be at index `j`.
4. Now there are two possibilities, either `A[ i ] + temp[ j ][ 0 ] > = K` or `< k`.
5. If it is greater than `K`, than check if `j - 1` exists or not and update `currentMaximum` if possible because this pair can be max and at the same time less than k because we found lower bound.
6. If it is less than K, than update `currentMaximum` if possible.

If you need indices than whenever you update you `currentMaximum`, store `i` and `j`.

**In this way you can find maximum sum of pairs such that it is less than K with original index as given in array B**

If order of elements does not matter than, just sort B and do same steps on B instead of temp.

#### Time Complexity

For sorting = O( len(B) * Log(len(B)) )
for traversing A and doing Binary Search on B = O ( len(A) * Log (len(B))) i.e, O ( nlog(n))